# Fastlane:iOS How to set up p12 certificate and PP file manually

Tags: ios, fastlane-gym

I am a new user of fastlane and stackoverflow，if there is any problem, please forgive me.
my developer p12 and pp file are created by Apple ID A,
distribution p12 and pp file are created by Apple ID B,
i got an apple ID C to public applictions.
All of the p12 and pp files are on my local computer.
Now, when I use the gym to pack automatically, how could I write the lane manual settings for the local p12 certificate and the PP files.

i didnt find any useful information from gym parameters,with my poor ruby knowledge and i even dont know how to use 'skip_profile_detection' .

this is my lane:

```
lane :beta do 

  Ipaname = get_version_number + '_beta_' + get_build_number + '.ipa'
  gym(#打包
    scheme: ENV['SCHEME_NAME'],
    export_method: "development",
    output_name: Ipaname,
    output_directory: "/Users/user/Desktop/"
  ) 
end
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand, but if the .p12 contains your cert and key, install it into keychain.  That's where the tools will look for it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.my English is not very good ,all i just want to express is that if i couldn't use git or  Apple Developer Portal ID to manage my .p12 and pp files.They're all stored in my computer only，how could i manually specify the corresponding certificate and pp file without install into keychain?Thx again:)!

Comment: Signing is controlled via the exportOptionsPlist -- you can find more here: https://possiblemobile.com/2017/09/xcode-9-code-signing-updates/ -- see signingStyle and signingCertificate -- you set the plist in gym with `export_options`

Comment: Gym just calls `xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath <xcarchivepath> -exportPath <destinationpath> -exportOptionsPlist <plistpath>` so if you can get xcodebuild to do it with the exportOptionsPlist, then you can set that up in gym as well

Comment: I have no idea if it's possible to get this to work without the keychain, but that's where I would look

Comment: thx for ur advice，i'll try as you suggest when i come back to work.thx again：）